# Where is my event tracking in Google Analytic?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I code my click event in my Angular like below:

```
onProductClicked() {
   (<any>window).ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'Click',
      eventLabel: this.item.provider,
      eventAction: 'click-on-product',
      eventValue: this.item.price + "~" + this.item.name
   });
}
```

And the above event triggers below request on my Chrome console:

https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j70&a=2055787371&t=event&_s=2&dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Diphone%2520x&dp=%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Diphone%2520x&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=mydomain.com&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=817x657&je=0&ec=Click&ea=click-on-product&el=Domain&ev=Rp%204.423.395%2C-~IPhone%206%20&_u=SACAAEAB~&jid=XXXXXXXXX&gjid=XXXXXXXXX&cid=XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X&_gid=XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX&_r=1&z=XXXXXXXXX

My question is, why the above event didn't captured in my Event dashboard in Google analytic dashboard?

[image]

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: How long ago did you create the google analytics account?  Are you seeing any other hits?

Comment: Since I also turn on SITE SEARCH feature in Google Analytic ... I can see that this has shown some ups and down line chart, and also list of search terms... so any other hits are working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not showing because the hit being sent is not valid, since the expected value type for Event Value (ev) is integer, not string.

Taken from Measurement Protocol's [Parameter Reference for ev:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ev)

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| Parameter | Value Type | Default Value | Max Length | Supported Hit Types |
+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| ev        | integer    | None          | None       | event               |
+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I would suggest to make the necessary modification, and try to send a hit via [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to make sure everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Google Analytics debug extension for Google Chrome to see if the event is firing correctly and registering in Google Analytics. If it is, then you are probably using filters in your Google Analytics account which block out the data in your Google Analytics view. The most common one I see is that you've filtered out your own IP from the website and therefore the event won't show up in your reports

Comment: My filters is empty.